# separate email from original email using perl

Tags: perl, email

When people email each other, they generally include the original email in their reply to a sender, adding a little more information each time to the email.  Each email client seems to have a different way of adding the original email to a reply.

I need to parse email arriving at our mail server and try and extract the new part of the message, and I'm wondering if there is a sensible way to strip this appended (or prepended) information (the "original message") and just get the new information in a mail body?  I believe sadly, that there is no encoding, the original email is simply added to the new message, but I thought I'd check with the experts?

thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to do that, in your mail client, mail server..?

Comment: I've edited the question, however I need to parse email on the mail server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simple, straightforward algorithm to separate quoted or forwarded text from new content. Quoting and forwarding are poorly standardized and different conventions have existed at different times.

Having said that, e.g. Google's Gmail succeeds fairly well in practice. With enough samples, you can clearly come up with reasonable heuristics.

Good indicators for quoted material are forwarded (pseudo-) headers and indented text, perhaps with a quote indicator along the left margin before the quoted text. You occasionally see outdents as well.

Traditionally, on Usenet in the early 1990s, people would use different, unique quoting styles.

```
: ~ | This seems to be the original.
: ~ This is the first reply.
: This is the second reply.

This is the third reply, quoting the 
previous three messages in sequence.
```

Around 1995, both clients and standardization initiatives by and large converged on "wedge" quotes;

```
> >> This seems to be the original.
> > This is the first reply.
> This is the second reply.

This is the third reply, quoting the 
previous three messages in sequence.
```

Then along came Microsoft and ruined it all. I suppose that top quoting makes sense in some corporate settings where you quickly need to collect all the background from a thread to a new participant, but even for that purpose it's a horrible abomination.

```
This is the third reply, quoting the 
previous three messages in sequence.

---- Begin forwarded message ----
From: Him [smtp:bogus]
To: His Friend
Subject: VS: Re: Same as on this message
Date: nothing machine-readable

This is the second reply.

---- Alkuperäinen viesti ----
Lähettäjä: His Friend [smtp:poppycock]
Saaja: Some Guy
Aihe: Re: Same as on this message
Päivämäärä: olisiko eilen ehkä

This is the first reply.

----- Original message ----
From: Somebody Else [smtp:mindless]
To: Some Guy
Subject: Same as on this message
Date: like, the day before

This seems to be the original.
```